# Проблема с занесением данных в бд sqlite3 с discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Код взят из ютуба, немного будет переделан в будущем, сейчас я хочу просто переписать всё у ютубера, чтобы потом переделать под себя конкретно, с изменением кода. Ошибка началась сразу, вначале кода. У меня создаётся база данных и идёт проверка на наличие пользователя в базе данных. База данных нужна для команды вывода баланса.
Вот код:

```
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass 

    connection.commit()
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\bot123.py", line 47, in __balance
    await ctx.send(f"""Баланс пользователя: **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**""")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Сама ошибка в команде, так как в базе данных нету данных о пользователе. Что делать????

Answer (score 0):

Проблема теперь в следующем: бот НЕ вносит данные о пользователе в БД(я ввёл сам и теперь команда работает)

```
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass 

    connection.commit()
```

Вот код, который не работает. Он должен заносить данные о пользователе в БД. Какие в нём ошибки?

Comment: Не стоит ответом дополнять свой вопрос. Для этого воспользуйтесь функцией редактирования своего вопроса и внесите в него изменения или дополните его новыми данными